# CSS top positioning in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have styled this code block while using Google chrome and as you see in this image it aligns fine.

[image: see image here]

However when viewing it with Firefox it doesn't display correctly

[image: see image]

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.full-panel select {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  background-color:#1B6B80;
  background-position:95% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border:1px solid #1B6B80;
  border-radius:2px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  display:block;
  font-size:10px;
  height:30px;
  line-height:10px;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:25px;
  position:absolute;
  right:150px;
  top:30px;
  width:150px;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="M7sQaw7MVFV4DQhoyMxdiuJPB7E5KbaWVB5U9lbp">
    <div class="full-panel">
        <input name="quick" value="1" type="hidden">
        <input class="biginput" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Set up your free website">
        <select name="domain_id">
          <option>mysite.com</option>
        </select>
        <input class="bigbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide the CSS that affects all elements in the HTML snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to use the position absolute be sure that its parent container has a relative position

```
.full-panel {
  position:relative;
}
```

This way you can start counting the pixels (top:30px) relatively to its container and NOT relatively to body